# java.lang.IllegalStateException: couldn't move cursor to position n

Tags: java, android, listview, android-cursoradapter, android-cursor

I am tying to import contacts and display it in a `ListView`. 
here is my cursor loader

```
        ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");


        mAdapter = new ContactsAdapter(getActivity(), cur, true, null);

        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
```

And my adapter is

```
for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {
        // do what you need with the cursor here
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        Log.e("name", name + "\n" + cursor.getCount());
        names.add(name);

    }
getIndexList();
```

and this is my bindview

```
@Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        // Gets handles to individual view resources
        final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        String displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

    String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));


for (phoneCursor.moveToFirst(); !phoneCursor.isAfterLast(); phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
        // do what you need with the cursor here

        String phoneNum = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        Log.e("phoneNum", phoneNum);
        mCheckBox.setTag(phoneNum);
        if (selectedNums.contains(phoneNum)) {
            mCheckBox.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            mCheckBox.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
```

My code crashes when `ListView` reaches to the end. If there is 2 contacts I am getting error
java.lang.IllegalStateException: couldn't move cursor to position 2
and similarly this is the case if I have n contacts. 
I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27748094/illegalstateexception-couldnt-move-cursor-to-position-x) but couldn't find any answer there. Please help

Here is the log

```
------------- beginning of crash
04-19 14:56:41.583 28188-28188/in.nuventure.com.wedding E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: in.nuventure.com.wedding, PID: 28188
java.lang.IllegalStateException: couldn't move cursor to position 2
      at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:248)
      at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
      at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
      at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
      at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:759)
      at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1659)
      at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2151)
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
      at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1037)
      at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:747)
      at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:761)
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
      at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1043)
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2086)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1843)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
      at android.app.Acti

04-19 14:56:47.361 28188-28200/in.nuventure.com.wedding W/CursorWrapperInner: Cursor finalized without prior close()
```

[image: here is screenshot of logcat]

I couldn't find the error line displayed. this makes me confused

Comment: position counting starts at number zero, so if you have 2 positions, then the first one is 0(zero) and the second 1(one). You are trying to get a position that is not there (in your case it will be the third one).

Comment: which line is the exact error line?

Comment: I have uploaded the log

Comment: the important part is missing from the logcat. The last line I see here in your post is pointing to the error line, please attach again....

Comment: the Logcat displayes only this much.

Comment: then scroll down. looke here: `at android.app.Acti` ..it´s the last line and it´s not complete....

Comment: see I have uploaded the screenshot of logcat

Comment: well, for any reason it´s cut off. maybe it helps if you switch from "Debug" to "Verbose" and reproduce the issue again...

Comment: and I think it will be better if you are getting the cursor count for the for loop by `phoneCursor.getCount()` and then the for loop: `for(int i=0;i>count;i++){}` . In the API `isAfterLast()` returns boolean for `whether the cursor is after the last result` . So I am not sure if the cursor still counts the item that is not there.

Comment: Yes the problem was with my `getcount()` which returned `names.size()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your help. This issue was with the `getCount()`. I did this before and I didn't notice  it later.

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return names.size();
    }
```

I removed this and it works fine. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
while (cursor.moveToNext()){
    //do something
}
```

In your for loop you are comparing if the cursor is not afterlast, that meaning, if it is the last one, it will still do the moveToNext, which doesn't exist

Or if you want to stick with your for loop just replace

```
!cursor.isAfterLast()
```

with

```
!cursor.isLast()
```